# Change Part of URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have URL like

- www.abc.com/pqr
- www.abc.com/sss/pqr/abc
- www.abc.com/ass/pqr/asd/dff

I want to change the pqr to some other word without affecting original functionlaity.

currently I had done something like this

RewriteRule ^pqr/(.*)  http://www.mysite.com/someotherword/$1 [L]

But it is affecting functionality like search, login. it is getting redirect the way i want it.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to replace the "pqr" part, this is the rewriterule:
RewriteRule ^(.*)pqr(.*)$ $1someotherword$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the query string is missing? Try:

```
RewriteRule ^pqr/(.*) http://www.mysite.com/someotherword/$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

**Alternates to POST data**

Use GET instead.

Use a Rewrite condition to not redirect files with POST data, store the data in the database, then call a redirect file, when the file opens on the new server, load the post data from the database.

Comment: It is Getting redirected but i am not getting POST Data. that is why search and login functionality is not working. i tried the Your answer as well but it is working same as mine. anyway thanks for instant reply.

Comment: Post data won't be sent to a new URL, it's a security issue.

Comment: So Is there any other way so that i can change part of url as well as post data?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati No, you can't rewrite/redirect with POST data