# How to match multiple segments in CodeIgniter routing

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to re-route my CodeIgniter URIs by changing the *controller names only* and leaving ANY OTHER SEGMENTS intact, regardless of how many there are (if any).

My controllers are using a single-level folder structure, such as **controllers/user/profile_controller.php**.

Each controller is called **[name]_controller** to distinguish it from other files/classes and avoid conflicts (ie. Users controller clashing with Tank Auth users model), but I want the URI to be:

```
/users/profile
```

Therefore, a simple route (that works) would be:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2_controller';
```

But the above doesn't allow for subsequent segments, and *I don't know how many there could be*. (:any) doesn't work because it only applies to single segments and obviously I don't want to write several routes for the potential number of segments, even if it is low.

I have tried a regular expression to match the rest of the URI (eg: users/profile/edit/123/abc), but the following doesn't work:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(.+)'] = "$1/$2_controller/$3";
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to match the remaining segments and put them back onto the re-routed URI?

Thanks in advance.
Mat

Comment: Note: Naming models with a '_model' suffix is my usual way around this but with external libraries I don't really want to rename them.

Comment: Would it help to make routes for one method parameter, and handle the remaining parameters in the method that uses them using `$this->uri->uri_segment()`?

Comment: You mean ignore the remaining segments in the route? How could I specify that in the route array key? It won't catch URIs that have more than the specified number of segments so it doesn't fire.

Comment: I would do this with .htaccess and use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592509/change-part-of-url-using-htaccess

Comment: Might give that a try thanks Luc